# Updating multiple plots in Jupyter notebook when a slider value changes

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I want to update multiple `imshow` plots in a jupyter notebook when an `IntSlider` value changes. What is wrong with by code?

Those are the versions I am using

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

print( 'versions: ipywidgets = ', widgets.__version__)
print( '          matplotlib = ', matplotlib.__version__)
print( '          numpy      = ', np.__version__)
```

This is the corresponding output

> ```
> versions: ipywidgets =  8.0.4
>           matplotlib =  3.5.0
>           numpy      =  1.20.3
> ```

And here is the code

```
def plot_image(ax, seed=0):
    np.random.seed(0)
    data2plot = np.random.rand(5,5)
    img = ax.imshow(data2plot)

fig = plt.figure( figsize=(12,6) )
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)

plot_image(ax1)
plot_image(ax2)

plt.show()

slider = widgets.IntSlider(value=0, min=0, max=100, step=1)

# callback function for the slider widget
def update(change):
    plot_image(ax1, seed=0)
    plot_image(ax2, seed=change.new)
    fig.canvas.draw()

# connect update function to slider widget using the .observe() method, observing changes in value attribute
slider.observe(update 'value')
slider
```

There is a slider, see the screenshot, and I can change its value, but it has no effect. What am I missing?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting together your code [what Markus suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78180592/8508004) with addressing two other issues with your implementation, this should work:

```py
%matplotlib ipympl
import ipywidgets as widgets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

def plot_image(ax, seed=0):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    data2plot = np.random.rand(5,5)
    img = ax.imshow(data2plot)

fig = plt.figure( figsize=(12,6) )
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)

plot_image(ax1)
plot_image(ax2)

plt.show()

slider = widgets.IntSlider(value=0, min=0, max=100, step=1)

# callback function for the slider widget
def update(change):
    plot_image(ax1, seed=0)
    plot_image(ax2, seed=change.new)
    fig.canvas.draw()

# connect update function to slider widget using the .observe() method, observing changes in value attribute
slider.observe(update, 'value')
slider
```

##### Details:

- [Markus covered the `np.random.seed(seed)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78180592/8508004).
- Syntax error: `slider.observe(update 'value')` should read `slider.observe(update, 'value')`
- As detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64335224/how-to-update-an-imshow-inside-a-ipywidgets-layout#comment113771862_64335224), you need the interactive matplotlib backend. See [the basic example in the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/ipympl/#basic-example) where you need `%matplotlib ipympl`.

Comment: Ahhh, `%matplotlib ipympl` did the job, thanks! (Plus fixing the indeed obvious bugs).

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is that the value of `seed` is never used within the function `plot_image`.
The first line of this function should probably be `np.random.seed(seed)` instead of `np.random.seed(0)`.
With this change, the second subplot should update when the slider is moved (the first panel will stay the same, since the seed is 0 independent of the slider value).

Comment: Yes, that is an embarrassing bug, thanks for discovering (not sufficient to solve the problem though, see @Wayne's answer)